# How to set text in a label on the right side?

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlabel

I've divided my space into two cols and I'd like to set labels on the left and right side, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFY8S.png

My code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
anotherPanel.add(panel);

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("text1");
panel.add(label1);

JLabel label2 = new JLabel("text2");
panel.add(label2);
```

I've tried with

```
label2.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

```
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("text2", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

is all you need.

or

```
label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

When in doubt -- check the [JLabel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)!

Comment: +1. No, No, No, Why! why! Why i could not see this question first. (EMO of a man trying to suicide) ;)

Comment: @whatissleep look at this respected man's smiling face: Hugged 40 points from all of us by answering it. If i answered this i could at least earn 20 points. Give me a reason not to be jealous!!